# Carrierwave upload - image or video

Tags: carrierwave

I have found [this link](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-do-conditional-processing) that explains how not to make thumbnails if the upload is not a video.

But how can I check, afterwards, if the saved file IS or IS NOT an image ? (In my case, I can store either images or videos), by calling a method on the model that holds the uploader ? DO I need some sort of callback in `is_image?(new_file)` that will set a field on the model ?

I'd like to be able to call `@model.is_image?`or `@model.iI would bes_video?` or maybe even something like `case @model.type; when :video ; ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a callback to set an attribute on the model that holds the uploader

```
# uploader/my_uploader.rb
...
def image?(new_file)
  if new_file.content_type.include? 'image'
    model.image = true
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

# models/my_model.rb (mongoid)
...
field :image, type: Boolean
mount_uploader MyUploader

# View
@my_model.image?
```